# What does the notation [n] in the phrase "For any subset S of [n]"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, information-theory

I'm trying to understand the sensitivity of boolean functions conjecture...

But alas, every paper/blog... uses this notation without defining it. (And it is almost impossible to google for notation)

[Example of use](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andris_Ambainis/publication/328137147_On_Block_Sensitivity_and_Fractional_Block_Sensitivity/links/5c346490458515a4c715320e/On-Block-Sensitivity-and-Fractional-Block-Sensitivity.pdf?origin=publication_detail)

Comment: It sometimes refers to the set of the first $n$ natural numbers,  $\{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$.  That certainly appears to be the intended meaning in the paper you link to.

Comment: It nearly always refers to $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: wikipedia has a list of math notations.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) does indeed have such a list, which lists 22 meanings for that symbol, none of which agree with the answers here. I suspect users lulu and mathworker21 are correct... Is there a reference that I could use to update that list and add yet another meaning?

Comment: ^I think Concrete Mathematics by Knuth, Graham and Patashnik uses this, and would make a fine reference. Do check before though, it has been ages since I last read the book.